# Objects Extending Scala traits. Ruby equivalent?

Tags: ruby, scala, traits

In Scala I can write a singleton Object that implements a trait.

```
trait Greeter {
  def greet = "Hello"
}
object MyGreeterObject extends Greeter
```

Then I can mock Greeter in my tests really easily

```
var mockGreeter = new Greeter { 
  override def greet = "I'm a mock"
}
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Ruby? Ultimately I want to be able to mock some methods that do not need state and are best served (in Scala anyway) by an object level method. And once I have this I want to be able to have a mock for my tests.

Comment: This is called Mixin in Ruby. You create one with the `module` instead of `trait`. (Modules are also used for namespace so don't get confused)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called Mixin in Ruby and it is implemented by Modules.

```
module Greeter
  def greet
    'Hello'
  end
end

# extending a specific object
o = Object.new.extend(Greeter)
p o.greet

# creating a specific class
MyGreeter = Class.new.extend(Greeter)
p MyGreeter.greet
```

But mocking is quite simple in Ruby. It doesn't depend on the way, your objects are constructed. Check the documentation of your favorite Ruby test framework.

```
o = Object.new
o.expect(:greet, 'Hi, I am a mock')
p o.greet
```

Comment: This is the same as creating an instance of a class that extends the mixin. I was hoping to start with a 'self' method e.g `p Greeter.greet`.

Comment: @OliverShaw It depends on your needs. You can use the `module` as namespace and define the method with `def self.greet ... end`. Mocking is as equal as with objects, `Greeter.expect(:greet, 'Mock')`.

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński Where is the main object extended? The code extends one specific instance of `Object` class I hope.

Comment: @sschmeck I think that's what I'm after. Thanks